# Enemy Random Spawn

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am making my first Unity game and I decided to make a 5 level shooter for mobile. I have made a random spawn script for my enemies, but the spawn is too frequent and generates too many at once.

Here is the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CreateRandomOctodeamons : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject enemyPrefab;
public GameObject enemyPrefab1;
public float numEnemies;
public float xMin = 19F;
public float xMax = 85F;
public float yMin = 3.5F;
public float yMax = -4.5F;

void Start () {

    GameObject newParent = GameObject.Find("1-background elements");

    for (int i = 0; i < numEnemies; i++)
    {
        Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(xMin, xMax), Random.Range(yMin, yMax), 0);
        GameObject octo = Instantiate(enemyPrefab, newPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        octo.transform.parent = newParent.transform;

        Vector3 newPos1 = new Vector3(Random.Range(xMin, xMax), Random.Range(yMin, yMax), 0);
        GameObject octo1 = Instantiate(enemyPrefab1, newPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        octo1.transform.parent = newParent.transform;
    }

}
```

Please look over it and let me know if I should change anything or add anything. I am also looking for a generic health script where I could just add my play prefab to allow his health to show above his head.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like 3 or more questions in one. I'll try to answer the question about "too many."

Try something like this:

```
void Start () {

    if (numEnemies < YourThreshholdForNumberOfEnemies)
    {
        GameObject newParent = GameObject.Find("1-background elements");

        for (int i = 0; i < numEnemies; i++)
        {
            Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(xMin, xMax), Random.Range(yMin, yMax), 0);

            GameObject octo = Instantiate(enemyPrefab, newPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                octo.transform.parent = newParent.transform;

            Vector3 newPos1 = new Vector3(Random.Range(xMin, xMax), Random.Range(yMin, yMax), 0);

            GameObject octo1 = Instantiate(enemyPrefab1, newPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                octo1.transform.parent = newParent.transform;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to declare a variable `YourThreshholdForNumberOfEnemies` and then also give it a value; try assigning a value of 2 to the variable. If you're new to programming, then I recommend you spend A LOT of time learning C# instead of trying to develop a Unity-based game. Yes, it's boring compared to games, but it's like eating a meal BEFORE you get to dessert :)

Answer (score 0):

well if you want you can use this

```
public GameObject[] obj; // for your enemies, using array so you can put many kind of enemy prefabs
public float spawnMin = 1f; //your minimum time enemies spawn
public float spawnMax = 2f; //your maximum time enemies spawn

void Start () 
{
    spawn();
}

void spawn()
{
    Instantiate(obj[Random.Range(0, obj.GetLength(0))], //instantiate random prefabs
        new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, z), 
        Quaternion.identity)

    //this is the one that control how many times spawn called
    Invoke("Spawn", Random.Range(spawnMin, spawnMax)); 
}
```